# remove parts of a line in a textfile after % except when prepended with \ in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract latex code from files but I do not want the comments; (comments start with a `%`). Comments are all the way to the line ending but I do not want to remove a literal `%` (prepended by `\` as in `\%`). How would I go about that? Ideally given this:

```
   Lamport and has become the dominant method for using \TeX; few
   people write in plain \TeX{} anymore. The current version is
   \LaTeXe. % this is a comment

   % This is a comment; it will not be shown in the final output.
   % The following shows a little of the typesetting power of LaTeX:
   \begin{align}
    E &= mc^2                              \\
    m &= \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
   \end{align}
   this is a \% literal symbol.
```

I would get :

```
   Lamport and has become the dominant method for using \TeX; few
   people write in plain \TeX{} anymore. The current version is
   \LaTeXe.


   \begin{align}
    E &= mc^2                              \\
    m &= \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
   \end{align}
   this is a \% literal symbol.
```

Is there a way to do that with Python?

EDIT after working solution, thanks to all of you.

```
   r'(.*)(?<!\\\)%.*'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a regex replace of `(?<!\\)%.*`, but this is brittle, e.g. `\verb!%!` probably isn't a comment.

Comment: interesting, how many other corner cases are there other than 'verb'?  is it a good idea to try to hunt them down and cover all of them?

Comment: Probably not. E.g. the `listings` package also has such a command and others can be defined as well. The only good way to parse LaTeX is to run it. That's the downside of Turing-complete document description languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can get inspiration from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82981/10250) on [tex.stackechange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). The idea is to:

1. replace `%` with another non-colliding symbol between `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` and in `\verb|...|`
2. to use the `(?<!\\)%.*` regexp to remove the comments
3. to change back the previous protected `%` symbols.

Note that in latex, the following

```
abc%comment
def
```

should be interpreted as

```
abcdef
```

Comment: i dont understand step 1, what is going on?

Comment: This is to protect `%` characters that are not starting comments, since `%` in `\verb||` or in `{verbatim}` the `%` characters are not specials. The linked answer give code in Lisp to do what you want and it should be easier to understand than my pseudo-code description.